# How to recover windows 8 when the partition containing User folder is deleted?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I installed Windows 8.1 in the C drive. But I moved the Users directory to a different drive in the SSD. Accidentally I deleted the SSD partition. Now when I boot into Windows many programs won't work and the modern start menu is blank. Can't search for apps. I tried to reset through the Windows 8 DVD but it failed. When tried to refresh Windows it said the partition is locked. When tried to reset it said a partition is missing. How can I recover my system?

Comment: Create a new user, delete the existing user, then create it again.  Since the User profile data is already gone you have nothing to lose.

Comment: @Ramhound When I go to the control panel and select create new user it won't respond. No new user menu!

Comment: Create the user through a command prompt then.